# Есть ли смысл применять индексаторы?

Tags: c#

Появилась необходимость разобраться с индексаторами. Тема не сложная но лучше проработать на будущее. Зачем они нужны? Я так понял для того чтобы при создании экземпляра класса мы могли сразу работать с несколькими экземплярами нашего класса, так что-ли? Почему бы нам просто не сделать коллекцию например для работы с несколькими экземплярами класса? Интересуют насколько полезно употреблять индексаторы? Они несут практическую пользу типо уменьшение затрат ресурсов на работу программы, или например ускорение работы программы?

Comment: Цитата "Индексаторы позволяют индексировать объекты и обращаться к данным по индексу. Фактически с помощью индексаторов мы можем работать с объектами как с массивами." Для этого и нужны.

Comment: Индексатор это то же свойство, только параметризированное, т.е семантически связанная пара методов (ну или один метод), но дополнительно несущее семантику Item. Вот вы и должны думать, должен ваш класс нести такой смысл или нет, это решение полностью на вашей совести. Любой код, использующий индексатор можно переписать без него, с обычными методами. Никаких ускорений или замедлений индексаторы не дают.

Comment: Что интересно, в CIL есть поддержка и других параметризированных свойств, помимо индексатора, чего нет в C#, но есть, например, в VB

Comment: Ну и как и любое свойство, индексатор может возвращать любой тип, например, если вы напишете класс шахматная доска, то он может возвращать с помощью индексатора конкретную ячейку: `Cell this[int x, int y] { ... }`